# How do you solve these recurrence relations for a closed form?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I'm not sure what methods are used to solve recurrence relations for a big-$O$ notation. Thinking about the problem conceptually doesn't really help me, but I feel like I could use some form of induction to come up with a tight upper-bound.

$$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{3})+T(\frac{2}{3}n)+n$$

$$T(n) = T(\frac{n}{7})+T(\frac{4}{14}n)+n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Akra-Bazzi method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) directly. For $T(n) = T(\frac{n}{3})+T(\frac{2}{3}n)+n$, we have $\left(\frac13\right)^p+\left(\frac23\right)^p=1 \implies p=1$, so that the asymptotic behavior is $$T(n)=O\left( n\left( 1+\int_1^n \frac{u}{u^2}du \right)\right)=O(n(1+\ln n))=O(n\ln n)$$

Similarily for $T(n) = T(\frac{n}{7})+T(\frac{4}{14}n)+n$, $\left(\frac17\right)^p+\left(\frac4{14}\right)^p=1 \implies p\approx0.4407$, so that

$$T(n)=O\left( n^{p}\left( 1+\int_1^n \frac{u}{u^{1+p}}du \right)\right)=O\left( n^{p}\left( 1+\frac{n^{1-p}}{1-p}-\frac1{1-p} \right)\right)=O(n)$$

Answer (score 0):

In $T(n) = T\left(\dfrac{n}{7}\right)+T\left(\dfrac{4}{14}n\right)+n$, this is consistent with $T(n) \le \dfrac{n}{1-\left(\frac17+\frac{4}{14}\right)}=\dfrac{7}{4}n$ since you would then have  $T\left(\dfrac{n}{7}\right)+T\left(\dfrac{4}{14}n\right)+n \le \dfrac{n}{4}+\dfrac{n}{2} +n = \dfrac{7}{4}n.$  So you can conclude $T(n)$ is $O(n)$.

You could do the same with $T(n) = T\left(\dfrac{n}{5}\right)+T\left(\dfrac{7}{10}n\right)+n$ and  $T(n) \le \dfrac{n}{1-\left(\frac15+\frac{7}{10}\right)}=10n$.

But you cannot do the same with $T(n) = T\left(\dfrac{n}{3}\right)+T\left(\dfrac{2}{3}n\right)+n$, since $1-\left(\frac13+\frac{2}{3}\right)=0$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? How do you find that $T(n) \leq x$ for $x = \frac{n}{1-(\frac{1}{7}+\frac{4}{14})}$? Why is $T(\frac{n}{7}) \leq \frac{n}{4}$ and $T(\frac{4n}{14}) \leq \frac{n}{2}$?

Comment: Also, then what can you do in the case of $T(n)=T(\frac{n}{3})+T(\frac{2n}{3})+n$?

Comment: On your first comment, if $T(n) \le \frac74n$ then $T\left(\frac{n}{7}\right) \le \frac74 \times \frac{n}{7} = \frac{n}{4}$.  And similarly with the others.

Comment: On your second comment, if $T(n) = T\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)+T\left(\frac{2}{3}n\right)+n$ then you can conclude $T(n) \not \in O(n)$

Comment: $T\left(\frac{n}{3}\right)+T\left(\frac{2}{3}n\right)+n$ is $O(n\log n)$. You might see if it is consistent with something like $T(n) \le \dfrac{n\log(n)}{\log(3/\sqrt[3]{2})}$ (unchecked)

Comment: Sorry, how do we know that $T(n) \leq \frac{7}{4}n$?